# Navigation using a Link's prop.href duplicates the Router basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out custom react-router navigation when the enclosing `BrowserRouter` component defines a `basename` property.

I am using the `Link component` property to render a link as a higher-order `Button` component (in this case from the Kendo UI library). The `onClick` reads the `href` prop to push navigation via history. However, the resulting URL repeats the base pathname.

In this example (React 17, router 5.2), if you navigate to `/area/simple` and click the Link (which has no child component), it takes you back to `/area`, but if you navigate to `/area/complex` and click the Button, it takes you to `/area/area`. (Inspecting `prop.href` shows that it is `/area`.)

Is history `push` the wrong way to navigate here? How does the anchor-based Link manage to navigate correctly?

```js
// imports omitted, Root is like App, it's a single-spa convention

const Root = () => {
    return (
        <Router basename="/area">

            <Route exact path="/">
                <h2>You Are Home</h2>
            </Route>

            <Route exact path="/simple">
                <h2>Plain Link Component</h2>
                <Link to="/">Go Home</Link>
            </Route>

            <Route exact path="/complex">
                <h2>Link with Child</h2>
                <Link to="/" component={ HomeButton }>
            </Route>

        </Router>
    );
};

const HomeButton = (props) => {
    return <LinkButton icon="home" {...props}>Home</LinkButton>
};

// normally a reusable component in a separate file
const LinkButton = (props) => {
    const { push } = useHistory();
    return (
        <Button onClick={() => push(props.href)} {...props}>{props.children}</Button>
    )
};

export default Root;
```

(I'm not interested in suggestions to re-style the Link as a button -- we're trying to stick to the built-in themed styles from the Kendo UI library, and replicating those accurately creates future maintenance headaches.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props for a custom `Link` render component aren't well documented, so we have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js) for the `Link` component to see what's going on.

#### Solution

Your custom link component is called with props `href` and `navigate`.

The `href` is for compatibility with the `a` tag more than anything else.  The default render component [`LinkAnchor`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/346153e38365e6a88657ce2e4e5acada290fc430/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L21) doesn't actually use the `href` for navigation at all.  It passes it to the DOM but the `a` tag that it creates intercepts clicks and handles them itself.

The `navigate` prop is what you actually want to use.  You simply call this function in response to a click.

```
const LinkButton = (props) => {
  return (
      <Button {...props} onClick={props.navigate} />
  )
};
```

#### More Info

Check out this section of the `Link` component source code:

```
const href = location ? history.createHref(location) : "";
const props = {
  ...rest,
  href,
  navigate() {
    const location = resolveToLocation(to, context.location);
    const method = replace ? history.replace : history.push;

    method(location);
  }
};
```

You can see how the `navigate` prop is created and what it does.  You can also see that the `href` is created from a separate method than the location.  The `href` needs to look normal to the user so it is the entire path to page including the `basename` `"/area"`.  Meawhile, `history.push` expects a relative location which does not include the basename.